# Can I use traits in this way?

Tags: php

At first I want to note that I know principles of OOP and I know what mean terms such as class, method, property etc.

Sometimes I need to create functions that are accessible in global scope and share data between themselves. For example I created in my project hooks mechanism based on concept from WordPress.

In WordPress there is $wp_hooks variable placed in global scope and there are add_action(), do_action(), add_filter(), apply_filter() functions. Each function imports $wp_hooks var by "global" keyword.

In my project I created class with only static methods and properties. Simple example:

```
<?php
class Hooks
{
    static private $_actions = [];
    static private $_filters = [];

    static public function addAction() { /* code... */ }
    static public function addFilter() { /* code... */ }
    static public function removeAction() { /* code... */ }
    static public function removeFilter() { /* code... */ }
    static public function runAction() { /* code... */ }
    static public function applyFilter() { /* code... */ }
}
```

I know that classes should not be used in this way. There is singleton pattern, but I don't like it and I don't want to use it in  my project.

Recently I learned by accident that I can use traits the same as classes with only static methods. In PHP is is possible to call public static methods in traits.

Class and trait have the same syntax and similar capability (both can contain functions and variables). But trait is only container, have not special meaning, when class have special meaning, idea — class in an abstract of some objects group in real (for example Person class or Product class).

And this is my question. Do you think that I will make mistake when I change "class" to "trait" in classes that are only containers and not real classes?

(Sorry for my English mistakes. ;>)

Comment: Please do not use WordPress as an example for anything related to software architecture/design. ;)

Comment: I used this comparison intentionally. ;-) I know that WordPress code is an example of badly designed code. And I think making classes/traits with methods is better than using variables in global scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not supposed to use Traits this way - they are more meant for inclusion in other classes - like mix-ins in Ruby. But like in Ruby, where mix-ins are implemented as modules and modules themselves can be addresses and their functiones referenced, so do traits in PHP can be addressed and their functions referenced:

```
trait Test {
    public function foo() {
        return 4;
    }
 }

 Test::foo(); // returns => 4
```

It may be "better style" to use traits for function collections, and it will definitely look prettier than a collection of static methods in an otherwise empty class, but neither of these are The **Right Thing(tm)**.

Comment: Yes, and in the case someone is at the point where they claim *"It's the only way"*, there always is another cleaner way!

Comment: I thank you very much for your response. There are some situations, when programmer can't find one good solution. ;)